# How to format out put as Json in flask get request

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am quite new to flask, 
Basically i have this code which returns multiple values

```
length= len(data['hits']['hits'])


for i in range(length):
  #print(i)
  #print (data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['message'])
  imei=((data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['GPS-LOG'].get("IMEI")))
  print ("imei: {}".format(imei))
  log_time=((data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['@timestamp']))
  print ("log time: {}".format(log_time))
```

out put :-

```
imei: 44444
log time: 2019-09-21T23:31:28.429Z
imei: 55555
log time: 2019-09-21T23:32:02.554Z
imei: 22222
log time: 2019-09-21T23:32:04.561Z
imei: 555555
log time: 2019-09-21T23:32:14.591Z
```

i am using that script inside flask GET method

```
@app.route('/battery/<string:get_imei>')
def get_battery(get_imei):
 length= len(data['hits']['hits'])
    for i in range(length):

    imei=(data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['GPS-LOG'].get("IMEI"))
    #print ("imei: {}".format(imei))
    log_time=((data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['@timestamp']))
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(log_time,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    new_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    d.strftime(new_format)
    print ("log time: {}".format(d))
    return jsonify ('{} {}'.format(imei, d))
```

but this does not return multiple values, its only return single value also Can i not make it json format like {'imei': '22222','logtime':'2019-09-21' },....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replacing `return jsonify ('{} {}'.format(imei, d))` with

```
return jsonify(imei = imei, logtime = d)
```

should get you expected result.

Comment: Thanks @Nadim Abrar, thats transform to json but its still not showing the multiple values, its only shows the last values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using JSON array. First you need to add each pair in a dict by iterating over the lists of values and appending dict to list. After this jsonify the list to get all values.
From your code block it looks like only first value will get returned because jsonify will only return JSON format on single values be it list or any other dict.

```
    #say you have two lists of imei and corresponding logtime
    imei=[44444,55555,22222,55555]
    logtime=['2019-09-21T23:31:28.429Z','2019-09-21T23:32:02.554Z','2019-09-21T23:32:04.561Z','2019-09-21T23:32:14.591Z']

    #to add each entry in JSON format in an array containing two fields, you need to create a temp dict and append it in list
    result=[]

    # we need to iterate over each element and add it to the dict and then add the dict to list
    for i in range(len(imei)):
        # it is creating a temporary dict and appending it to the result list (array)
        tempDict={'imei':imei[i],'logtime':logtime[i]}
        result.append(tempDict)

    # after this return the result as JSON    
    return jsonify(result=result)
```

Your output will look like this

```
{"result":[{"imei":44444,"logtime":"2019-09-21T23:31:28.429Z"},{"imei":55555,"logtime":"2019-09-21T23:32:02.554Z"},{"imei":22222,"logtime":"2019-09-21T23:32:04.561Z"},{"imei":55555,"logtime":"2019-09-21T23:32:14.591Z"}]}
```

[image]

Here is similar thread : [Flask-Json How do i return mutiple rows as json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523027/flask-json-how-do-i-return-mutiple-rows-as-json-objects)